# MS Access database query using SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm currently working with a simple database for the attendance of the professor in our college. I'm using MS Access 2010 with a Main table that includes the Attendance log of all the professor with their information such as ID number, Surname, Firstname, Login and Logout.

I just wanted to ask how to create a query on filtering the records based on id number of the professor in order to view their login/logout information in one specific table.

The Main table includes the ff:

```
ID Num   |Surname  |Firstname  |Login   |Logout
1002      LName3     FName3     10:30pm  11:00pm
1000      LName1     FName1     12:00pm  12:30pm
1001      LName2     FName2     14:00pm  15:00pm
1001      LName2     FName2     16:00pm  17:00pm
```

I want the output to be like this:

```
_For LName1, FName1 (IDnum=1000)_
Login      |  Logout
12:00pm  12:30pm

_For LName2, FName2 (IDnum=1001)_
Login      |  Logout
14:00pm  15:00pm
16:00pm  17:00pm

_For LName3, FName3 (IDnum=1002)_
Login      |  Logout
10:30pm  11:00pm
```

Thank you!!

Comment: This is extremely basic stuff to do with SQL, and it is even more basic in Access where you could instead create a Report that does all the magic for you!

Comment: I just wanted the output to be in a table form so that I can interface it in our project. By the way our project is a microcontroller-based project that can check the attendance of the profesor using RFID then display the records of each professor in a touch screen LCD.

Comment: @Kei , your question is very broad? Throwing micro-controllers and RFID into the mix, on that level of engineering, you should be on top of basic SQL queries of you plan to use them? I don;t think we can quite figure out if you are asking a question, or asking for a tutorial on Basic SQL?

Comment: honestly, I'm a beginner in sql as well as MS Access. So, I badly need a tutorial for this. Currently, I can create a table using a query. I just needed to know how can I automatically run the query so that, the table is updated once the 'Main' table adds a new record.

Comment: You need to do some goog'ling about starting out with using SQL on your chosen platform.

Comment: And your database design is all wrong. Store professor names in  a table called Professors with an ID, use that ID in your main table to indicate which professors. You are making it extremely difficult for yourself if you do not properly normalize your database. http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm  BTW You are talking about an 'ID' - where is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Currently, I can create a table using a query. I just needed to know how can I automatically run the query so that, the table is updated once the 'Main' table adds a new record.

You may not need to "create a [new] table" at all. If you create a saved "Select Query" in Access (also known as a "View" in other database applications) then any time you reference that saved query you will get the most current information from the main table. So, for example, if your [MainTable] contains

```
ID Num  Surname  Firstname  Login     Logout  
------  -------  ---------  --------  --------
  1002  LName3   FName3     22:30:00  23:00:00
  1000  LName1   FName1     12:00:00  12:30:00
  1001  LName2   FName2     14:00:00  15:00:00
  1001  LName2   FName2     16:00:00  17:00:00
```

and you create a saved query in Access named [ActivityFor1001] that looks like this in Design View

[image: DesignView.png]

then it will return this

```
ID Num  Login     Logout  
------  --------  --------
  1001  14:00:00  15:00:00
  1001  16:00:00  17:00:00
```

If a new row is added to the main table:

```
1001  LName2   FName2     20:00:00  21:00:00
```

then the next time you run the saved query it will return

```
 ID Num  Login     Logout  
------  --------  --------
  1001  14:00:00  15:00:00
  1001  16:00:00  17:00:00
  1001  20:00:00  21:00:00
```